# Diferença entre null e clear() em uma ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, gerenciamento-de-memória, null, garbage-collector

Qual a diferença entre:

```
arrayList.clear();
```

e

```
arrayList = null;
```

Os dois não destroem todos os elementos da `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não.

Como o próprio nome diz o primeiro limpa todos os elementos (torna os elementos `null`) e o `ArrayList` passa ter zero elementos (o `size` é mudado) e você pode continuar manipulando-o. Não quer dizer que vai economizar memória.

O segundo destrói a referência nesta variável (coloca uma referência para 0) impedindo que ela acesse o objeto `ArrayList` e impossibilitando você usá-lo com esta variável. Você pode até criar outro objeto e armazenar na mesma variável, mas será um objeto novo. Se não houver mais referências para este objeto ele fica na memória, indisponível, até o *garbage collector* coletá-lo da memória. A variável (ou seja a referência para o objeto que será 0 enquanto não apontar para um objeto) continua existindo e até que outro objeto seja vinculado a ela, nada poderá ser feito a não ser, obviamente, armazenar um novo objeto `ArrayList`, permitindo então todas as operações que esta classe pode realizar.

Você pode achar que o resultado é o mesmo. E pode até ser dependendo do que você quer. Conceitualmente o primeiro faz mais sentido se você quer limpar os elementos e começar de novo com o `ArrayList`. Setar `null` em uma variável `ArrayList` significa que você não precisa mais dela e normalmente é desnecessário.

Em Java e muitas linguagens modernas (que possuem GC rastreador) costuma ser desnecessário tomar qualquer providência para dizer que não precisa mais de uma variável e que não quer mais uma referência para um objeto, basta deixar de usá-la. Claro que pode haver casos em que você sabe que vai demorar muito ou nunca vai haver a liberação desta variável e isto pode ser considerado um vazamento e memória e *setar* `null` para esta variável pode ser uma opção para liberar a memória se souber que ela é a única referência para o objeto.

É situação rara mas é bom saber que mesmo com GC existe a possibilidade de vazamento de memória, e saber como lidar com ele. Não saberia citar todos os exemplos em Java, mas se a variável for estática ou está em um objeto (como membro ou em método) criado e mantido no início da aplicação/*thread*. Em C# sei que este vazamento pode ocorrer em eventos ([*observer pattern*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101)) se o programador esquecer de liberar o objeto no momento do último *unsubscribe*.

Estes códigos têm resultados "mais equivalentes":

```
arrayList.clear();
```

e

```
arrayList = null;
arrayList = new ArrayList();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Collections/Clear.java).

Desta forma as operações seguintes em cima da variável `arrayList` podem ser feitas da mesma maneira em um `ArrayList` "limpo". Mas chegou-se ao mesmo resultado com técnicas diferentes com características diferentes e performance diferente, embora seja pequena e provavelmente irrelevante na maioria dos casos. A segunda pode gerar mais pressão no GC.

Comment: "O segundo destrói o `ArrayList` impossibilitando você usá-lo" **se** essa for a única referência pra ele, é claro. Se houver outra referência para o mesmo `ArrayList` pode-se continuar usando-o normalmente, só que não através dessa variável.

Comment: @mgibsonbr bem observado, vou editar.

Comment: então, para o último exemplo... No meu caso eu teria que usar o clear mesmo já que é um arrayList global que será reutilizado, mas eu tenho um outro ArrayList (private), que armazena dados selecionados de uma GridView (Android), então ele será usado várias vezes, quando a pessoa clicar no botão ou cancelar a ação o arrayList ficara desnecessário, então eu teria que apenas criar um novo ArrayList quando for necessário? ou seria bom setar NULL, levando em conta que Android usa Dalvik

Comment: É difícil fazer uma avaliação sem ver o todo (o todo mesmo) mas como eu disse, usar um `null` quase nunca é a solução. Se a variável deixa de ser usada de verdade, ela será eliminada mesmo que não estabeleça o `null`. Não sei se você veio de alguma linguagem que isto era necessário (algumas obrigavam setar um `null` para liberar a memória). Em Java isto é desnecessário. Claro que você pode estar fazendo alguma outra coisa errada e esta variável possa estar sobrevivendo sem necessidade, mas não é porque esqueceu de setar `null`. Se eu vejo isto em um código, logo procuro por algum outro erro.

Comment: Não digo isso pelo fato do java ter uma coleta automatica, mas digo por exemplo no caso do Android que é um sistema bem mais limitado e não usa a mesma vm que o Java para desktop, usa o Dalvik. Eu sei que o GC 'roda' depois de um determinado tempo e não no exato tempo em que a variavel não é mais utlizada... Por isto perguntei sobre o Android se seria realmente necessário para melhorar a performance. Não executar o GC, mas setar arraylist para null, principalmente quando o arraylist possui muitos dados

Comment: Entendo sua preocupação mas não há problema, porque o GC roda conforme a necessidade da plataforma mesmo sendo uma implementação diferente. Se não há referências para o objeto e há pressão na memória, a coleta vai ocorrer. Se não há pressão na memória, o que importa os dados continuarem lá na memória? Isto não é vazamento de memória. Está lá porque ainda pode estar sem causar problemas. Vazamento seria só se tivesse que ser eliminado mas não pode porque ainda tem uma referência desnecessária para o objeto. Aí tem que descobrir porque esta referência está viva. Mas não é porque faltou `null`.

Comment: Depende de implementação mas note que o `clear()` não precisa impedir uma coleta do objeto desnecessário. Internamente o `ArrayList` abandona objetos internos várias vezes conforme ele vai crescendo. E esses objetos abandonados são coletados. Mesmo que o `ArrayList` em si não seja liberado, pelo menos os elementos dele eu te garanto que serão liberados com o `clear()`. A não ser que o Dalvik tenha uma implementação muito porca :)